# which is the different ea pronunciation : really /ideas/disappear/mean

Tags: pronunciation

a couple of my classmates and I had a discussion about which is the different word.Some said it's ideas, others said "mean". and as a follow up questions does the sound of "ea" change between ideas and idea. We checked some dictionaries but we had conflicting results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Sara Jaidi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Are you asking which of these words use the most common English pronunciation of "ea" and which are (relative) outliers? If not, please clarify what you mean by "the different word." Thanks!

Comment: different word as in the "ea"  sound is pronounced differently .to add some context this words are part of an english test we did today .we were asked to corss one word from the four.We will correct it next week but since it caused contreversy i came here to ask native speakers opinion.i'll be sure to report back next week if  decisive answer is not found .Thank You ^^

Comment: Of the 4 words, only "mean" does not have both vowels pronounced.

Comment: @KristinaLopez in British phonetics that is correct.  In US phonetics *idea* is the only one that has both pronounced.  Reference: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/idea

Comment: Sorry, @spirographer, but  I'm a native US English speaker and where I'm from (Chicago), "really" and "disappear" both have a two-vowel dipthongy pronunciation.  "Really" is a 3-syllable word, albeit the "a" is unaccented, and "disappear" is a 4-syllable word.

Comment: @KristinaLopez we can't rely on local usage in general.  My spouse is from Chicago and doesn't pronounce *really* or *disappear* the way you suggest.

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs, if not dipthongs.

Answer (score 3):

As shown by the other answers and comments, it depends on the dialect. It is therefore a bad question for a test (unless you are being tested on your knowledge of a specific variety of English;
if that is the case, please tell us which one).

In standard English, I would say pretty confidently that *mean* and *idea* are not considered to have the same vowel sound(s). But the vowel sound(s) in *disappear* may be considered closer the *mean* vowel by some speakers, and closer to the *idea* vowel by others. Yet others might say it's a third sound distinct from both of these. It really depends. There's a similar range of variation for *really* (just to give an example, I usually don't  pronounce it with the vowel of either *idea* or *mean*, but that of *silly*).

I can't think of any reason why *idea* and *ideas* would be pronounced with different vowel sounds. They're the same for me aside from the final consonant.

Answer (score 0):

In Australian English, "idea" remains a standard diphthong (sounding like I-deer, fear, pier), and doesn't rhyme with IKEA.  Similarly, the plural "ideas" sounds as I-dears.  Of your list of 4-5 words, "mean" is very different in its "ea" pronunciation to the others.

Comment: How doesn't it rhyme with IKEA? Is is that *idea* has two syllables, while *IKEA* has three?

Answer (score -1):

*Idea* is the only one where the **ea** is not a diphthong, but two separate vowels. The diphthong in *Really* is sometimes split into two vowels for emphasis.

Comment: is there a difference between idea and ideas ?

Comment: No, but there are nonstandard accents that add an *r* to the pronunciation of *idea*, and in thos accents there is a difference.

Comment: What are the "standard accents" in this context?  As a speaker of middle-class "standard" Australian English (that is more similar to British middle-class "standard" English than it is to (say) rural or working-class "Strayan"), we have an "r" sound in "idea" and "ideas", however does that make it nonstandard? And there is no different "ea" sound for "idea" and "ideas".

Comment: @Cargill my bad, I was more thinking of non standard American accents than anything else.  Definitely a minority of English speakers add this intrusive *r*.  Here's a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R

Comment: Indeed ... one of the defining (distinctive) markers of AusE is its non-rhotic nature (so tuna and tuner are homonyms), but we are fairly prone to the intrusive and linking / r /, certainly.